# Access svg attributes from index.html in d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to replicate this `d3.js` worldmap:

https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/backgroundmap_basic.html

However I want to reorganize the code into two parts, `index.html` and `Worldmap.js`,

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Worldmap</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=Worldmap.js></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <svg id="my_dataviz" width="400" height="300"></svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

`Worldmap.js`:

```
// The svg
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

// Map and projection
var projection = d3.geoNaturalEarth1()
    .scale(width / 1.3 / Math.PI)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])

// Load external data and boot
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world.geojson",
   function(data){

    // Draw the map
    svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(data.features)
        .enter().append("path")
            .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
            .attr("d", d3.geoPath()
                .projection(projection)
            )
            .style("stroke", "#fff")
})
```

However I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: node is null

selection_attr https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js:1835
<anonymous> Worldmap.js:6
```

What am I doing wrong here?
I suppose the `d3.js` cant select the `svg` attributes from the index.html?

Comment: Move `<script type="text/javascript" src=Worldmap.js></script>` inside body. Do you still get the error?

Comment: Thanks for your input. The error is gone, but no worldmap shows up.

Comment: To make a script file run **after** the DOM is parsed (and the ``<svg>`` element exists), set the ``defer`` attribute; ``<script type="text/javascript" defer src=Worldmap.js></script>`` It doesn't matter *where* you put the ``<script>`` tag then

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman thanks that worked! So my error was that I tried to alter an ``<svg>`` Element that was alreadyexisted in the parsed DOM?

Comment: No, ``var svg = d3.select("svg")`` was looking for an ``<svg>`` element in the DOM.. which wasn't there yet. In the olden days people would have adviced to put the ``<script>`` all the way at the bottom of your HTML file. See [DOM 101 Lesson](https://gist.github.com/ermogenes/49c16a7486d09792747db452bf3ae0d5)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman but isnt there ``<svg>`` in the ``body`` tag?

Comment: Yes, but an HTML file is _parsed_ from **top to bottom**; so if you execute a ``<script>`` (without ``defer``) at the top of your HTML file, the ``<svg>`` does not exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `d3.json` as a Promise:

```
const url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world.geojson";
d3.json(url)
  .then(drawMap)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

2. Call projection with data:

```
.attr("d", d => d3.geoPath().projection(projection)(d))
```

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const width = parseInt(svg.attr("width"));
const height = parseInt(svg.attr("height"));

// Map and projection
var projection = d3.geoNaturalEarth1()
    .scale(width / 1.3 / Math.PI)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])

// Load external data and boot

const drawMap = data => {
    // Draw the map
    svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(data.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
            .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
            .attr("d", d => d3.geoPath()
                .projection(projection)(d))
            .style("stroke", "#fff")
};

const url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world.geojson";
d3.json(url)
    .then(drawMap)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="500" height="500" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However this only works if I put all of this into the same file. If I try the aproach with two seperate files, like in the OP, it doesnt work.

Comment: Add `console.log(svg)` right after `const svg = d3.select("svg");`

Comment: Also, put `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => console.log('READY'))` in the first line of your JS file and see if it comes before the previous console log.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks again for your help. The ```console.log('READY') comes after the ```console.log(svg)``.

Comment: Add `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onReady)`

Comment: ... and `const onReady = () => { ... all the code in worldmap.js ... }`

Comment: I put everything, including ``const document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onReady)``, into the anonymous function, however the map doesnt load.

Comment: Add `console.log(data)` inside drawMap. Do you see the loaded data?